# Syntactic sugar for throwing with null coalesce operator

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar

Let's suppose we want to throw if we try to assign null to something, what about this trick:

```
public static class ExceptionExtension
    {
        public static T Throw<T>(this Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

that we can use for example like this:

```
 return possibleNull  ?? new Exception("Unspecified something....").Throw<string>();
```

do you think it is a good/worst/useless practice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no sense to me - not very readable. I would expect the second argument of the `??` operator to be of the same type of `possibleNull`, not to throw an excpetion.

I would much rather see:

```
if(possibleNull == null)
{
  throw new Exception("Unspecified something....");
}

return possibleNull;
```

Comment: Yes Oded it is a trick, it seems nice to me, but just want other opinion, thanks! (+1) I wait some others before mark your as a reply.

Comment: @FelicePollano - I understand. When I write code, there are a couple of things I like to keep in mind (since others will read it). 1. [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). 2. This quote: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live." by John F. Woods.

Answer (score 2):

You could always stick it in some sort of short-named static helper class:

```
public static class Never
{
    public static T Null<T>(T value)
        where T : class
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return value;
    }
}

myClass.AProperty = Never.Null(somePotentiallyNullValue);
```

Your other example wouldn't make much sense, I'd opt for calling it "useless" practice.

Adding a bit of "fluency" to helper classes tends to focus on making things more readable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: in which case could not compile ?

Comment: @FelicePollano the `return val ?? throw new`

Comment: It compile since you can specify the return as generic: unfortunately it can't infer.

Comment: @FelicePollano for `return t ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();` I get a compiler error `Invalid expression term 'throw'`

Comment: @FelicePollano Ah I didn't notice the OP wasn't throwing the exception, just returning it, which won't work if the types aren't compatible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It could be better and more readable to create some kind of static helper class that throws
Like this

```
public static class ThrowHelper
{
    public static TException ThrowIfNull<TException>(object value)
        where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        if (value == null) //or other checks
        {
          throw new TException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider it a good practice.

First, the extension method itself just introduces a method for something we already have a keyword for: throw. This might be confusing. It declares a return type though it will never return a value, just to please the compiler in the context where you want to use it. Referring to what others already pointed out, that's rather a "principle of most astonishment".

Then, looking on how you would employ this method, the resulting code seems not very clear to read. Even worse: you can only use this approach in an expression, so you would always end up with code that uses an object in some way (in your example: just return it) and checks it for null as a side effect in the same line. I'd prefer doing null checks explicitly and not mixed with something else. A library like [CuttingEdge.Conditions](http://conditions.codeplex.com/) can help to reduce the amount of code you have to type for this. You would use it in your example this way

```
Condition.Requires(possibleNull , "possibleNull ").IsNotNull();
return possibleNull;
```